Series.std() not consistent on identical numbers?
import pandas as pd
print(pd.Series((0.19, 0.19)).std())
print(pd.Series((0.19, 0.19, 0.19)).std())
print(pd.Series((0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19)).std())

Why the first and third row give 0, but the second does not? Is it a bug?

This is due to how floating point arithmetics works

@mozway: Pandas uses degrees of freedom to compute the standard deviation. s=  sqtrt(1/(n−ddof)*sum(xi-xbar)**2)). This is where the difference comes from. It can actually countered.

I realize, this is what you meant.
